# How can i connect an existing python script in sql?

Tags: python, sql-server

I want to run an existing python project in sql server management studio.How can i do this ?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-python-in-sql-server-2017-to-obtain-advanced-data-analytics/

Comment: @SanjeevS this is not connecting to SQL from Python, it's connecting to Python from MSSQL.